# Android retrofit 2 multipart image upload not working for Tablet Device

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 multipart for high quality Image upload (around 12 MB image). It works fine if I uses a Mobile Phone. But when I use Tablet it does not work. Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
public interface ApiDataService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("API Path Here")
    Call<UploadImageResponse> Upload(@Header(Constants.KEY_AUTHORIZATION) String authorization,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                     @Part("userId") RequestBody userId);
}


public class RetrofitInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getInstance(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Then I am using following method to Upload Image on server:

```
public void callUploadImageApi(String token, String fileName, String userId){
    ApiDataService apiDataService = RetrofitInstance.getInstance().create(ApiDataService.class);
    token = "Bearer "+ token;
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File dir = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApplication/"+ fileName);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                    dir
            );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", dir.getName(), requestFile);

    // add another part within the multipart request

    RequestBody userIdString =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, userId);


    Call<UploadImageResponse> call = apiDataService.Upload(token, body, userIdString);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadImageResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Response<UploadImageResponse> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    //success code here
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            //failure code here
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me...

Comment: You should tell what goes wrong. Only then we can help maybe.

Comment: Hi, Actually I have added a success code and a failure code, it is not calling any of them.

Comment: You have told nothing about the differences of the two devices.

Comment: `FileOutputStream outStream = null;` ???

Comment: About the devices, it is working fine when I am using any mobile phone, but when I am using Tablet, specially "Samsung Galaxy Tab A" it seems not working. And about "FileOutputStream outStream = null;" I am not using it, so you can ignore it.

Comment: Im not interested in name of phone and tablet but in their differences.

Comment: There is no difference between them both have android 10 OS. Just 1 thing tablet has 2 GB RAM and the mobile phone has 4 GB.

Comment: `File dir = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApplication/"+ fileName);` Why are you calling a file `dir`? Confusing. Same path on both devices? Who put that file there? Normally such a path is not accessable on an Android 10 device. You did not tell why your app can access it.